# Какой кусок кода исполняется в Django, когда я отправляю форму для сохранения записи в админке?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Есть проблема, что при добавлении записи либо при ее изменении в админке выходит ошибка

> page not found

Причем это происходит только при **POST** запросе и наличии в форме `input type=file`. Хочу сделать отладку но не знаю какой кусок кода срабатывает при добавлении записи. Может кто знает?

[image: Ошибка при добавлении записи с файлом]

Спасибо Михаил Алексеевич. Это показало где именно происходит ошибка. Вот только я ничего не понял. Может вы поймете?

Trace back: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Debug=True`, ниже опуститесь, там будет лог.
"Кусок кода" который в вашей вьюхе написан, следует посмотреть туда.

Comment: Я бы для начала попробовал manage.py makemigrations , manage.py migrate.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Делал, проблема не в этом. Эта проблема происходит на Cpanel, а локально все работает

Comment: ~Citizen , там у Вас apache? Попробуйте выключить Debug = True, вывод покажет 404 соответствующего сервера :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Да apache, поставил Debug = False, выдала просто ошибку "Not Found. The requested URL /admin/main/gallery/add/ was not found on this server".

Comment: Хорошо, понятно. Можете предоставить секцию INSTALLED_APPS =  из settings.py ?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'main',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

Comment: Получается, у Вас модель Gallery в  приложении main?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Да

Comment: Решение Вашего вопроса ниже. У меня работает.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы узнать место возникновения ошибки можно использовать handler404 в urls.py + sys + traceback:

**urls.py:**

```
        import sys, traceback
        from django.http import HttpResponse

        def test_404(request):
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            ex_info = traceback.format_tb(exc_traceback) + \
                      traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value,
                                                  exc_traceback) +  \ 
                      traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value,
                                      exc_traceback)
            return HttpResponse(str(ex_info), status=404)


        handler404 = test_404
```

Будет работать только при

```
DEBUG = False
```

В **settings.py**